# Firebase Firestore prevents Gradle from completing build

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

It shows this error whenever I try to sync the Gradle. Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream

I'm using AndroidStudio 3.1.3. I also followed the documentation on Firebase on how to get started but it dosen't work. I have tried to search and I couldn't get much information. I read about excluding the protobuf but it dosen't really work too.Thanks in advance for the help.

Also apparently commenting out the line with Firestore works so the issue is something with the Firestore dependency.

Below is my build.gradle for app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    //on laptop
    //buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application_id_name(sanitized)"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'project.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    api 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.27.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'

    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my build.gradle for the project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Got this error when trying to exclude protobuf.Could not find method com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2() for arguments [build_60vj88gllutj4zz7i0ca1ojkd$_run_closure2$_closure7@3b52fa7d] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'{
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

to this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

to be able to use the latest version of firebase libraries.

After executing the `./gradlew :app:dependencies` , you can see that both `'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'` and `'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.27.0'` are depending on `protobuf`, thus leading to this problem.

Since Op is not using `google-cloud-storage` then removing `'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.27.0'` fixed this issue.

Comment: Hmm. Upgraded but still does not work. Same error showing up

Comment: try it without excluding `protobuf`, also use firebase-auth 16.0.2

Comment: 16.0.2 also throws this error. Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream. Have removed the exclusion of protobuf. Tried moving down all the way to 15.0.0 then it works. Will it have any negative implications of using an older dependency?

Comment: did you use version 15.0.0 for firestore or auth?

Comment: Will also try test it out with codes later to see if using an older dependency affects the API. Will update here again once fully tested

Comment: Version 15 for firestore. My auth dosen't seem to be giving me any issues. Have been using it for some time

Comment: You can find the release notes here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android